# Cohomology groups $H^p(K;Z)$ where $K$ is finite simplicial complex are finitely generated abelian groups

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I am very new in studying algebraic topology and cohomology.
$C^p(K;G)=Hom(C_p(K),G)$ are cochains of $K$, $Z^p(K;G)$ are cocycles, i.e. kernels of delta homomorphisms, $B^p(K;G)$ are coboundaries of delta homomorphisms and $H^p(K;G)=Z^p(K;G)/B^p(K;G)$ are cohomology groups of $K$ with coefficients in $G$. [Munkres, Elements of algebraic topology, chapter 42]

Since we can easily see that if A is free abelian group of finite rank n, then Hom(A,G) is isomorphic to $G\bigoplus G\bigoplus ... \bigoplus G$ (n summands), one can conlude that $Hom(A,\mathbb{Z})$ is isomorphic to n summands $\mathbb{Z}$, so it is a free abelian group of rank n, when A is free abelian group of rank n. 
So, when we take K to be a finite complex, cochains are free abelian groups of finite rank, which means we can repeat the story of homology groups?

Am I right?

Comment: $Z_p$ is a subgroup of a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module of finite rank, so it is finitely generated (since \mathbb{Z} is Noetherian). Therefore $H_p$ is finitely generated too, being a quotient of $Z_p$. This does not imply that $H_p$ is free, though.

Comment: Yes, though of course cohomology and homology don't necessarily coincide. In general, $H_*(\operatorname{Hom}(C_*, G))$ is not the same as $\operatorname{Hom}(H_* C_*, G)$; the main result here is the universal coefficient theorem (for cohomology), which shows that the expected map $H_*(\operatorname{Hom}(C_*, G)) \to \operatorname{Hom}(H_* C_*, G)$ is a surjection and gives a precise form for the split kernel. (I'll also throw in an unsolicied plug for Hatcher over Munkres' book, which is tedious, pedantic, and drains any enjoyment out of one of the most fun areas of math. I hate that book.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is correct.  More generally, the same conclusion holds as long as $G$ is finitely generated.  More surprisingly, this conclusion actually doesn't depend on $K$ being finite: it only depends on the *homology* of $K$ being finitely generated.  Proving this requires a much more careful analysis of what happens to homology when you apply the functor $\operatorname{Hom}(-,G)$, known as the *universal coefficient theorem*.